# Visual Basic ODBC AS400 iSeries crypto

Tags: vb6, odbc, adodb, ibm-midrange, cryptography

I am using a **ISeries Access ODBC Driver** to retrieve data from a **AS400**.

The connection code looks something like this:

```
Set myConnect as new ADODB.Connection

With myConnect
.CursorLocation = adUseClient
.Provider = "MSDASQL.1"
.Open "User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Data Source=<dsource>"
End With
```

This worked fine up until now.

The problem is that we have recently introduced encryption to some *(ColOne)* of the library columns.

A inline SQL string that used to look like this:

```
SELECT ColOne FROM libOne.ColOne WHERE ColOne = <val>
```

Now needs to look like this:

```
SELECT F_DecFld('FieldIdentifier',ColOne) AS ColOne FROM libOne.ColOne WHERE ColOne = <val>
```

I know the F_DecFld() function resides in the crypto library, I have included it in my ODBC and when I run the same query in WinSQL (Also uses the ODBC) it returns the data as expected, **but from my program it returns the data without decrypting (no error).**

The only thing I can think of at this point is that the **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8** Library is not taking the **F_DecFld()** into consideration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**crypto** library needs to be added to the AS400 user profile and not just in the library list on the ODBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

Get an ODBC trace as per http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzaii/rzaiiodbc17.htm to see a detailed accounting of what is going on (and hopefully an error message from the driver)